# Subclass a view in django-registration-redux

Tags: django, django-views, subclass

I'm using [Django-registration-redux](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) and I want give more data to a view to render my base template. I read the [example in doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).

My `url.py`:

```
class MyPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all() # example in doc
        context_dict = services.get_base_data_for_views(request)
        return context_dict

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/password/change/', MyPasswordChangeView.as_view(
    success_url=reverse_lazy('auth_password_change_done')), name='auth_password_change'),
    ...
]
```

I have the extra data in services.py but this code gives error:

```
name 'request' is not defined
```

So `context_dict` isn't defined. Where can I take my request from? Mainly I need the user (but `print(user)= 'user' is not defined`). Or should I write another function?

Comment: Note that if you want to include the variables from `get_base_data_for_views()` in all views, then it might be better to create a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In methods of Django class based views, you can [access the request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) with `self.request`.

```
class MyPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context_dict = services.get_base_data_for_views(self.request)

    return context_dict
```

Therefore you can access the user with `self.request.user`. Normally you would want to use [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) or [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) so that only logged-in users can access the view, but in your case `PasswordChangeView` takes care of that for you.